# Convert datetime to timestamp in Elixir

Tags: datetime, timestamp, elixir

I am looking for opportunity to convert `DateTime` to unix timestamp. Is there any function that handle it?

Comment: `Ecto.DateTime` was deprecated ages ago, wasn’t it?

Comment: Somewhat along these lines should work: `edt |> Ecto.DateTime.to_erl() |> NaiveDateTime.from_erl() |> DateTime.from_naive() |> DateTime.to_unix()`.

Comment: @Thanks for mentioning it. I realized that the type I am working is %DateTime. However it is still the question. How can I convert %DateTime to timestamp?

Comment: With [`DateTime.to_unix/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#to_unix/2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert a `DateTime` to a unix timestamp by using [`DateTime.to_unix/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#to_unix/2):

```elixir
datetime = DateTime.utc_now()
DateTime.to_unix(datetime)
```

---

If you just want the current timestamp: [`System.os_time/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#os_time/0):

```elixir
iex> System.os_time()
1663383246024939000
iex> System.os_time(:second)
1663383248
```